# Solving ODE, check my answer.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve this ODE but I'm not sure with my answer. Anyone please check my answer. If my work is not true, tell my mistake. Thanks.

> Solve the ODE $$\left(x^2+2xy\right)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y^2-2xy.$$

**Solution**.

\begin{alignat}{2}
 && \left(x^2+2xy\right)\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=y^2-2xy\nonumber\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&\left(y^2-2xy\right)dx-\left(x^2+2xy\right)dy&=0\nonumber\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&\left(\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^2-2\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)\right)dx-\left(1+2\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)\right)dy&=0.
\end{alignat}
Let $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$, then $y=ux$. We have
\begin{alignat}{1}
 dy&=u dx+xdu\label{p8}
\end{alignat}
and
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &&\left(u^2-2u\right)dx-\left(1+2u\right)dy&=0.\label{p9}
\end{alignat}
Now, we have
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &&\left(u^2-2u\right)dx-\left(1+2u\right)\left(u dx+xdu\right)&=0\nonumber\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&\left(u^2-2u\right)dx-\left(u+2u^2\right) dx-\left(1+2u\right)xdu&=0\nonumber\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&\left(-u^2-3u\right)dx-\left(1+2u\right)xdu&=0\nonumber\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&\left(u^2+3u\right)dx&=-\left(1+2u\right)xdu\nonumber\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&\dfrac{dx}{x}&=-\dfrac{1+2u}{u^2+3u}du\label{p10}
\end{alignat}

By Integrating last equation, we have
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &&\int \dfrac{dx}{x}&=\int -\dfrac{1+2u}{u^2+3u}du\nonumber\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&\ln x &= -\left(\int \dfrac{2u+3}{u^2+3u}du
 -
 \int \dfrac{2}{u^2+3u}du
 \right)\label{p11}
\end{alignat}

We find the integral on RHS as below.
\begin{alignat*}{1}
 \int \dfrac{2u+3}{u^2+3u}du&=\int \dfrac{1}{u^2+3u}d\left(u^2+3u\right)\\
 &= \ln(u^2+3u)\\
 &= \ln u +\ln(u+3)
\end{alignat*}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
 \int \dfrac{2}{u^2+3u}du&=\int \dfrac{2}{u(u+3)}du\\
 &=\int \dfrac{\frac{2}{3}}{u}du + \int \dfrac{-\frac{2}{3}}{u+3} du\\
 &=\dfrac{2}{3} \ln u-\dfrac{2}{3}\ln{\left(u+3\right)}\\
\end{alignat*}

Now we have
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 &&\ln x &= -\left(\left(\ln u +\ln(u+3)\right)
 -
 \left(\dfrac{2}{3} \ln u-\dfrac{2}{3}\ln{\left(u+3\right)}\right)+C
 \right)\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&\ln x &= -\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\ln u +\dfrac{5}{3}\ln(u+3)
 \right)+C\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&\ln x &= \ln \left(u^{\frac{1}{3}}(u+3)^{\frac{5}{3}}\right)^{-1}+C\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&x &= K\left(u^{\frac{1}{3}}(u+3)^{\frac{5}{3}}\right)^{-1}, \text{ } K=e^C\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&x &= K\left(\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\dfrac{x}{y}+3\right)^{\frac{5}{3}}\right)^{-1}.
\end{alignat*}
We get the general solution of ODE
$$x = K\left(\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\dfrac{x}{y}+3\right)^{\frac{5}{3}}\right)^{-1}.$$
or we can write
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 &&x &=  K\left(\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\dfrac{x}{y}+3\right)^{\frac{5}{3}}\right)^{-1}\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&x\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\dfrac{x}{y}+3\right)^{\frac{5}{3}} &=  K\\
 \Longleftrightarrow\quad
 &&\left(\dfrac{x^4}{y}\right)\left(\dfrac{x}{y}+3\right)^{5} &=  c, \text{} c=K^3.
\end{alignat*}

Comment: I solved the ODE and I obtained: $-\frac{5}{3}\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}+3\right)-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\ln(x)+c$.

Comment: It's same with my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Not the same. Note that $u=\frac yx$, not $\frac xy$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake is $u=\frac{x}{y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that $$-\frac{5}{3}\ln(u+3)-\frac{1}{3}\ln(u)=\ln(x)+c \overbrace{\implies}^{u=\frac{y}{x}}\boxed{-\frac{5}{3}\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}+3 \right)-\frac{1}{3}\ln \left(\frac{y}{x} \right)=\ln(x)+c}$$